# ffmpeg: control PAT period and PMT offset

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, encoding

I'm using ffmpeg to convert a stream from HD to SD.  I'd like to keep all the other parameter values (e.g.: GOP, PAT period, etc), so I've specified most of them in my command:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mpg -g 24 -vf scale=720:576 -b:v 3.2M -bufsize 4.8M -pcr_period 0.01 -sdt_period 1.6 -pat_period 0.25 -f mpegts output.mpg
```

However, I can't control PAT/PMT period nor the offset between PMT and PAT packets (it used to be more than 20ms in the original stream and now it's ~0.5ms). I can't find any documentation to control those parameters and https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mpegts doesn't give much information about them. Any suggestion?

Comment: Your link goes to the demuxer help. You want the muxer section. As per that, you should set `pcr_period` as an integer (I guess, in ms)  and add `-muxrate` *value* where value is in bits. Add `-v 40` to get a readout when executing the command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I wanted to link the muxer section, I copied the wrong URL.pcr_period in ms doesn't change my PAT period nor the offset of PMT packets. What value should I set for muxrate?

Comment: Don't know about muxrate value but you have to set one else the pcr period is ignored. Try 5M.